# Unrecognized image file format for .PNG images gwt compilation failed

Tags: gwt

I am using gwt 2.1.0 ClientBundle for ImageResource, i have .png transparent images i am getting the follwing issue.

It is not consistently coming it's working in some machines and not in some machines

> Invoking generator com.google.gwt.resources.rebind.context.InlineClientBundleGenerator
>                  Preparing method getFlightFilename319
>                     Adding image 'com.delta.acs.snapp.gates.web.client.resources.FlightImages.getFlightFilename319'
>                        [ERROR] Unrecognized image file format
>                  [ERROR] Generator 'com.google.gwt.resources.rebind.context.InlineClientBundleGenerator' threw an exception while rebinding 'com.delta.acs.snapp.gates.web.client.resources.FlightImages'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this has to do with the version of Java installed on the machines.  Make sure your machines have a somewhat current version of Java 1.6.0, preferably 1.6.0_25 or greater.  Upgrade one of your machines to a newer version of java and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Thanks Kyrra, its due to version changes only other machines have 1.6_11 mine is 1.6_21.. after

Answer (score 0):

I can not understand why you suggest to change JRE !
Only try to change colorspace to RGB or sRGB or RGBA.
I do this with linux :

```
convert old_image.png -define png:color-type=2 new_image.png 

file old_image.png new_image.png 
old_image.png    PNG image data, 48 x 48, 1-bit grayscale, non-interlaced
new_image.png    PNG image data, 48 x 48, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```

now you can use new_image.png and this problem fixed without any other modification on your GWT project .

Java : 11.0.8 2020-07-14 LTS
GWT  : 2.9.0